# a mark up language for making (online self-grading where possible) tests and quizes based on LaTeX

Tags: blackboard, auto-multiple-choice

I want a quiz and test creating mark-up language that's like LaTeX (and integrates LaTeX) along with dynamic problems, randomized versions of problems etc. A feature-rich open source test and quiz mark-up language with a lightweight engine to deploy it.

Has this been done?

All of these quiz creation softwares (blackboard....) want me to click on a ton of dumb menus and I just want to type and not slow down to write math.

That "feature rich" is really the catch. Blackboard has all the features built up for their years of working with colleges and universities. So, they have things like ... rubrics! and a ton of question formats ... and on and on. But, I just feel like I'm FIGHTING the interface every single day since I've been forced to put my course online.

Comment: I think you should ask in Stack Overflow. The closest thing in the TeX and friends that allows customisations and programming is LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into some non-GUI/web way to create the problems for Blackboard.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you are looking for something like [eqexam](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqexam?lang=en) bundle.